# How do I compute the variance of a column of a sparse matrix in Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a large `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` and would like to normalize it. That is subtract the column mean from each element and divide by the column standard deviation (std)i.

`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` has a `.mean()` but is there an efficient way to compute the variance or std?

Comment: I was going to post some python code to calculate the variance in a vectorized fashion, but if you "normalize it" you will not have any zero elements left, so before I do, please tell us that you are not messing up your sparsity structure anyways.

Comment: That is a very very good point Sebastian, thank you. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can calculate the variance yourself using the mean, with the following [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition):

```
E[X^2] - (E[X])^2
```

`E[X]` stands for the mean. So to calculate `E[X^2]` you would have to square the `csc_matrix` and then use the `mean` function. To get `(E[X])^2` you simply need to square the result of the `mean` function obtained using the normal input.

Comment: To square the matrix, for simplicity: `c = matrix.copy(); c.data **= 2` and then `c.mean(0); del c` (could only replace `.data`). But I maintain that the OP sounds wrong saying to substract from all elements.

Comment: My understanding was that this calculation was generally very numerically unstable, as you can end up subtracting two floats of similar magnitude whose only difference is in rounded off portions of the significand.

Answer (score 1):

Sicco has the better answer.

However, another way is to convert the sparse matrix to a dense numpy array one column at a time (to keep the memory requirements lower compared to converting the whole matrix at once):

```
# mat is the sparse matrix
# Get the number of columns
cols = mat.shape[1]
arr = np.empty(shape=cols)
for i in range(cols):
    arr[i] = np.var(mat[:, i].toarray())
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I know of is to use `StandardScalar` from `scikit`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


scalar = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
scalar.fit(X)
```

Then the variances are in the attribute `var_`:

```
X_var = scalar.var_
```

The curious thing though, is that when I densified first using `pandas` (which is very slow) my answer was off by a few percent. I don't know which is more accurate.

Comment: We have a numerical stability problem in the sparse implementation of `StandardScaler`:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19546

Answer (score -4):

The efficient way is actually to densify the entire matrix, then standardize it in the usual way with

```
X = X.toarray()
X -= X.mean()
X /= X.std()
```

As @Sebastian has noted in his comments, standardizing destroys the sparsity structure (introduces lots of non-zero elements) in the subtraction step, so there's no use keeping the matrix in a sparse format.

Comment: This is not actually true. Using the formula in Sicco's answer allows to use sparsity to reduce computing time.

Comment: For very large matrices, this answer doesn't even fit in memory, whereas the other answer runs pretty smooth and fast.