# How to speed up calculating variance among sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

Thank you for your help. Let me explain my question more clearly.

I have several coo_matrix M with same shape. Indexes of each matrix represent a journal pair. Each element represents the frequency of a journal pair. For example,
for all matrices, [1,2] gives the frequency of journal pair 1-2; [2,1] gives the frequency of journal pair 2-1.

My goal is to get the variance of frequency for each journal pair.

Comment: Subtracting or adding to a sparse matrix breaks the sparsity. Probably want to use `Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2` formula instead (which only subtracts after taking averages). Difficult to say more unless you post the code or a more complete description of your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute the variance of a column of a sparse matrix in Scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169611/how-do-i-compute-the-variance-of-a-column-of-a-sparse-matrix-in-scipy)

Comment: Can you clarify in your question: do you have a list of `scipy.sparse` matrices all of which have the same shape, and you would like to compute the elemente-wise variance across the matrices? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (correct me if I'm wrong) you are hoping to compute the elementwise variance across a list of sparse matrices all of which have the same shape. For example, you could have 100 sparse matrices each of size 200 by 300 as below.

```py
from scipy import sparse
matrices = [sparse.random(200, 300) for i in range(100)]
```

You can compute the elementwise mean of these matrices by summing them up and dividing by the number of matrices in the list.

```py
def get_elmwise_mean(matrices):
    return sum(matrices) / len(matrices)
```

From the elementwise mean you can compute the elementwise variance using either of the formulas:

1. `Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2`
2. `Var(X) = E[(X - E[x])^2]`

#### Using formula 1.

```py
squared_matrices = list(map(lambda mat: mat.power(2), matrices))
elmwise_var = get_elmwise_mean(squared_matrices) - get_elmwise_mean(matrices).power(2)
```

#### Using formula 2.

```py
elmwise_mean = get_elmwise_mean(matrices)
squared_matrices = list(map(lambda mat: (mat - elmwise_mean).power(2), matrices))
elmwise_var = get_elmwise_mean(squared_matrices)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me explain my question more clearly.

I have several coo_matrix M with same shape. Indexes of each matrix represent a journal pair. Each element represents the frequency of a journal pair. For example, for all matrices, [1,2] gives the frequency of journal pair 1-2; [2,1] gives the frequency of journal pair 2-1.

My goal is to get the variance of frequency for each journal pair.

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I should use x.power(2) rather than np.power(2) to solve this question.[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ofqP.png)